# How to display parentheses in the title of Jenkins with Jelly?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

How to display parentheses in the title of Jenkins with Jelly?
I have below codes.

```
<f:entry title="${%Loop Timeout(seconds)}" field="loopTimeout">
    <f:textbox value="300"/>
</f:entry>
```

But it only display **Loop Timeout** on the screen. How to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, use get function to return a fix value from the class. without using hardcode in jelly.